# Setting Property on UIButton in Loop

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, selector

I'm spinning in circles on the best way to implement this, so maybe you can help me out:

*How can I make it so when the UIButton responds to the selector `highlightImage`, it also can set the desired challengeId = the index of my `appDelegate.availableArray`?*

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I'm creating a `UIScrollView` with buttons:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tv.frame.size.width, 78)];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 78)];

    [self createScrollButtons];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:scrollView];
```

---

My `createScrollButtons` loops and creates buttons in the `scrollView` as so, looping over the number of elements in my `availableArray`

```
- (void) createScrollButtons
{
    SuperHeroGameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SuperHeroGameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    NSLog(@"Challenge array = %@",appDelegate.availableArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < [appDelegate.availableArray count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@" ID= %d", [[[appDelegate.availableArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"id"] intValue]);
        [self createButtonAtX:x AndY:y withChallenge:[[appDelegate.availableArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"id"]];
        x += 90;
    }

}
```

---

`createButtonAtX andY withChallenge is called for each element in`availableArray`, positioning them correctly along the scrollView.

```
- (void)createButtonAtX:(int) x AndY:(int) y withChallenge:(id)challengeId
{
    CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(x, y, 80, 78); 
    ChallengeButton *capeButton = [ChallengeButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [capeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [capeButton setFrame:buttonRect];

    [capeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(highlightImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIImage *capeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CapePower.png"];
    [capeButton setBackgroundImage:capeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [scrollView addSubview: capeButton];
}
```

---

`highlightImage` is called as each buttons selector, to determine which button is pressed.  (and ideally with element from the `availableArray` that button is associated with)... I've subclasses UIButton and added an `int` value to be able to call `[sender setChallengeId:]`

```
- (void) highlightImage:(id)sender
{

    if([sender isSelected] == NO){
        [sender setSelected:YES];

        [sender setChallengeId:selectedChallenge];
        NSLog(@"sender = %d",[sender challengeId]);     
        UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PowerBarHand.png"];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    }
    else {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HandstandPower.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        selectedChallenge = 0;
    }
}
```

My problem is I cannot figure out how to get the appDelegate's `availableArray` element INTO my highlightImage, as UIButton's `[capeButton addTarget:challengeId action:@selector(highlightImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]` will not allow me to pass the challengeId from the loop earlier in the flow.

I am able to pass any integer value to setChallengeId, and it is handling as expected.  I just need to get the `appDelegate.availableArray` `id` value from the loop.

Any direction would be great!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `availableArray` into `highlightImage:` the same way you got it into `createScrollButtons`:

```
SuperHeroGameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SuperHeroGameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and then access `appDelegate.availableArray`.

I think that's not the question you actually meant to ask, though. I think what you want is to call `setChallengeId:` on each ChallengeButton as you create it in `createButtonAtX:AndY:withChallenge:`. Then in `highlightImage:` do `selectedChallenge = [sender challengeId]` rather than `[sender setChallengeId:selectedChallenge]`.

Comment: For the question I asked, this was even more of an answer than I was looking for.  Anomie, you are a true lifesaver:)  So, if I transition from this view to the next, what's the best way to access each specific `ChallengeButton`'s challengeId?

Comment: I think I might have answered my own question:)